GCP VPC connector unable in country. Unable to connect from cloud functions to PostgresSQL
I have created multiple Cloud Functions to process files from a Google Cloud Storage. Additionally, I have also created a PostgresSQL within GCP. This is the main process:

when a file lands into a bucket, it gets processed
it extracts some data and inserts the data into the Postgres SQL

I have read from Connect from Cloud functions with regards to this, it mentioned that I have to have a VPC connector that is within the same region.
However, I am unable to create said connector as it is not available for the region.

Does anyone know a solution/alternative method to solve the issue? Thank you very much.

I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

The error Missing data from regions us-west8 (not supported yet) means that the region you used is not yet supported. You can check this document for supported regions for serverless vpc.
Serverless VPC Access connectors are supported in every region that supports Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, or App Engine standard environments.
Both postgresql and cloud functions are not supported in us-west8.
I suggest you create a Serverless VPC Access connector in the same VPC network as your Cloud SQL for Postgresql instance or Cloud functions.
To check available regions you can use following command:
gcloud compute networks vpc-access locations list

